# Ajax Laravel search wont work : Cant find the class

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

so this is the code :

```
  <?php

class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('search.index');
    }

    public function postSearch()
    {
        $return = array();
        $term = Input::get('term');

        $books = array(array('name' => 'Alice in Wonderland', 'author' => 'Lewis Carroll'),array('name' => 'Tom Sawyer', 'author' => 'Mark Twain'),array('name' => 'Gulliver\'s Travels', 'author' =>'Jonathan Swift'),array('name' => 'The Art of War', 'author' => 'Sunzi'),array('name' => 'Dracula', 'author' => 'Bram Stoker'),array('name' => 'War and Peace', 'author' =>'LeoTolstoy'),);

        foreach ($books as $book) {
            if (stripos($book['name'], $term) !== FALSE) $return[] =$book;
        }

        return Response::json($return);
    }
}

?>
```

and this is route :

```
Route::controller('search', 'SearchController');
```

and html :

```
<div id="results"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#search-form").on("submit", function(e) {e.preventDefault();
            var search_term = $("#term").val();
            var display_results = $("#results");
            display_results.html("loading...");
            var results = '';
            $.post("search/search", {term: search_term}, function(data) {if (data.length == 0) {results = 'No Results';
            } else {
                $.each(data, function() {
                    results += this.name + ' by ' + this.author + '<br>';
                });
            }
                display_results.html(results);
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

now this is the error :

```
Class SearchController does not exist
```

everything seems ok but whats the problem ? it cant find my class ........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Is this a new controller?  running `composer dump-autoload` will add it to your `autoload_classmap`

Comment: i ran the code you gave , still the same error

Comment: Is your controller inside a namespace?

Comment: i ve updated the full code

Comment: Which part of your code gives you the error?

Comment: Is your search controller named SearchController.php?

Comment: yes it is named exactly that , and error is on ControllerInspector

Comment: @ Greatone did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue...